# VLOOKUP where lookup value is a day

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm trying the get the average value out of this table that has a lot of data in it.

I tried to VLOOKUP function but i can't get it to search on day names :(
If someone could help me that would be much appreciated!!

[image: I've attached an image to help :)]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20dBF.png)

Answer (score 0):

This basically the same as answer already given but for text and for all averages to return

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT($B$2:$B$15,FIND(",",$B$2:$B$15)-1)=$H2),D$2:D$15)/SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT($B$2:$B$15,FIND(",",$B$2:$B$15)-1)=$H2))
```

Put in I2 and drag right and down.

[image: Data]